# Oracle 11g to Oracle 12c character set conversion (dump)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, character-encoding, oracle12c, utf

I am currently migrating a system from Oracle 11g to 12c.

The 11g Server (Source) uses WE8MSWIN1252 character set,
the 12c Server (Target) uses AL32UTF8 character set.

We use EXP and IMP to transfer the data for one schema. German umlauts are not correctly transferred. Also some fields are getting too long for the target as they get longer trough UTF representation.

What are the correct settings for EXP and IMP to achieve a correct and lossless conversion with imp/exp?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Disclaimer: Sometimes I don't know what I'm talking about, so view this with skepticism. With that said: the length problem can be solved because Oracle 12c allows VARCHAR2 up to 32,767 bytes (vs. 4,000 bytes before). Use that option. (I don't see how you would solve that problem otherwise, unless you are willing to change the datatype to CLOB - which seems unnecessary given the other solution). Then, I would do the conversion to AL32UTF8 in the Source DB first, and make sure everything looks OK before migrating. It is always best to make such changes one step at a time.

Comment: There's a problem though: doing that in the Source db will push you into the length limit problem. If it affects only a small number of values, you could split them in two, and then combine them back after transfer. However, this is manual work. If you have more than a very small number of values affected, you may be better off changing data type to CLOB in the Source, transfer as CLOB, and then convert back to VARCHAR2 in the Target (with the `max_string_size = extended` option). It's still a lot of work to convert columns to CLOB on the Source though... (and then back in the Target).

Comment: I will solve the length problem by increasing vchar sizes in the source database. Still, I don't understand the complete character set stuff...

Comment: Why are you using exp / imp? Why not use expdp / impdp?

Comment: I must admit tjat I am not used to these tools, but I suspect, I would have run into the same trouble -see my Answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried all different NLS_Settings, conversions of meta settings to no avail. Later I discovered that some tables had correct umlauts after the migration, some had typical two character thingies like "Ã¼" for german "ü".

As the application worked well on the old database I suspect that due to an error in an older version of the application some of the umlauts were coded to different codepoints resulting in the same character but being split through the process of migration.

The simple solution I found was to create a small PL/SQL block that corrects all umlauts across all varchar fields in all tables. This is kinda brute force solution but as experimenting with IMP/EXP takes a very long time this was the most feasable way to solve my problem in reasonable time.

```
begin
  for c in (select a.table_name,b.column_name from all_tables a 
  left join all_tab_columns b on a.table_name=b.table_name and b.owner='<myschema>'
  where a.owner = '<myschema>' 
  and (b.data_type='VARCHAR2' or b.data_type='VARCHAR'))
  loop
    execute immediate 'update ' || c.table_name ||
    ' set ' || c.column_name || '=
      replace(
        replace(
          replace(
             replace(
               replace(
                 replace(' || c.column_name || ',''Ã„'',''Ä''),
               ''Ã¤'',''ä''),
             ''Ã¼'',''ü''),
          ''ÃŸ'',''ß''),
       ''Ãœ'',''Ü''),
     ''Ã¶'',''ö'')';
  end loop;
end;
```

And yes, there is no conversion for 'Ö', I did not find any in the database as only few german words start with 'ö' and even less are capitalized ;-)

Perhaps this approach can solve as a quick fix for anyone running into the same problems.

Answer (score 0):

To change the database character set, perform the following steps:

```
1.Shut down the database, using either a SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE or a SHUTDOWN NORMAL statement.

2.Do a full backup of the database, because the CSALTER script cannot be rolled back.

3.Start up the database.

4.Run the Database Character Set Scanner utility.
CSSCAN /AS SYSDBA FULL=Y...

5.Run the CSALTER script.
@@CSALTER.PLB
SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE; -- or SHUTDOWN NORMAL;
STARTUP;
```

Note that the CSALTER script does not perform any user data conversion. It only changes the character set metadata in the data dictionary.Thus, after the CSALTER operation, Oracle will behave as if the database was created using the new character set.

Comment: Thanks. May be I miss something but will this really allow transferring the data correctly? As 12c does only allow UTF character sets, I cannot create the database as it was in 11g.

Comment: Hi, go to the following link for more details. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96529/ch10.htm

Comment: @PeterR, it's a bad idea to provide this link. `ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET ...` is not supported anymore (it was de-supported at 10.1). Use this one instead: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch11charsetmig.htm#NLSPG011